# In bash, my for loop returns too many results

Tags: bash

so I'm trying to compare user lists in bash, file vault enabled users vs users I've defined. As a test I ran:

```
for i in "$ulist"; do
  if ($i == *testuser*) || ($i == *otheruser*)
  then
    echo "dont' change $i"
  else
    echo "change $i"
  fi
done
```

but it only returns

```
testuser
otheruser
x
y
change z
```

for the record:

```
ulist=$(fdesetup list | cut -d',' -f1)
```

any idea why it just cycles through the whole list without really comparing it the way I want it to? In the end I want to be able to skip modifying the users that I've told it skip.

Comment: The code you post contains syntax errors and could not possibly return the output you report. For a start, see http://shellcheck.net/ and fix the errors it points out.

Comment: Quoting the `for` argument produces exactly one iteration.

Comment: Yeah, I'm very new to bash, but I found that it's very hard to compare an array against another array and produce what I want. I ended up just finding a way to only get the result I wanted without having to check through two arrays. I'm still having tons of other small issues but so far this hurdle has been crossed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, I'm very new to bash, but I found that it's very hard to compare an array against another array and produce what I want. I ended up just finding a way to only get the result I wanted without having to check through two arrays. I'm still having tons of other small issues but so far this hurdle has been crossed.
I did end up using grep to find the user and awk to print just the first column I wanted. This was my first Stack post, thanks for the help all.

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you actually want is something like

```
fdesetup list |
grep -vE '^(test|other)user,'
```

If you really want the verbose do/don't output, change the `grep` to a simple `sed` script which does that.